# Dissappearing characters in youtube-dl, ffmpeg, and windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, cmd, youtube-dl

so what happens is that if the video title has a symbol that isn't supported by your current locale then ffmpeg won't be able to get to that file properly.

Here's one example

```
►2 HOURS BEST MELODIC DUBSTEP MIX APRIL 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ
```

as you may or may not be able to see, lots of symbols from unicode.

The problem is that in cmd and ffmpeg, though cmd can see

```
►2 HOURS BEST MELODIC DUBSTEP MIX APRIL 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ
```

ffmpeg only sees

```
2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013 ヽ(≧ω≦)ﾉ
```

This is the exact error message (i'm using youtube-dl)

```
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\►2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4'
ERROR: C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013 ヽ(≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4: No such file or directory
ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe
```

After some research i've determined that by changing the system locale you can change which symbols cmd can support.

However

```
ヽ
```

Used to appear as a box in a question mark in United states locale. In japanese locale it appears as it does on your screen right now.

the problem with

```
◄
```

is that even though it's not appearing as a question mark in a box (it's appearing as how it should be), ffmpeg (or cmd) can't detect it properly.

(Refer back to the error message, i'll repost it below.)

```
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\►2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4'
ERROR: C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013 ヽ(≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4: No such file or directory
ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe
```

So as you can see, I think cmd passed on the symbol correctly to ffmpeg seeing from the adding metadata line, but when it actually does the operation ffmpeg loses

```
► and ◄
```

Could this be a bug with ffmpeg? MY workaround so far with incompatible symbols was to change the system locale, but I don't think i can do that with these two symbols...

These are the unique characters that i need to have a locale that supports

```
Ö

◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ

( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

(_≧∇≦)

†

【
```

More info on the problem in general

```
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/2999
```

and this is what's going on (Batch Script)

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd C:\youtube-dl

set /p "var1=Enter URL: " %=% pause
if defined var1 set "var1=%var1:"=%"
set "var2=%date:/=-%" 
set "var3=%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"
youtube-dl "%var1%" -ci -o "C:\Music\ToBeDone\%var2%\%var3%" -f best -x --no-mtime --add-metadata 
youtube-dl "%var1%" --skip-download -ci -o "C:\Music\ToBeDone\%var2%\Thumbnail\%var3%" --write-   thumbnail
youtube-dl "%var1%" --skip-download -ci -o "C:\Music\ToBeDone\%var2%\Description\%var3%" --write-description
```

Comment: While this is a real problem, this isn't a programming question and is not suitable for StackOverflow. It probably belongs on http://superuser.com/ instead. Also, it would be a good idea to post this further information in the Github issue you linked (for example, it would be useful to Philipp Hagemeister to see the batch script you're using).

Comment: Also, what version of youtube-dl are you using? (Run `youtube-dl --version` to check). Have you run `youtube-dl -U` to update to the latest version, where you bug might be fixed? If not, that should be your first step.

Comment: @rmunn   Actually i was trying to talk to philipp but i think he kinda ignored me and i have the latest version of youtube-dl.

Comment: You shouldn't expect to get a personal response from the developer to say "Yes, I'm working on your bug". There are about 3000 issues filed on Github; if he responded personally to all of them, he wouldn't have time to actually *fix the problems*. :-) Be patient, and refrain from pestering him. The more you "poke" him and say "Is it fixed yet? Is it fixed yet?" the longer actually fixing it will take, because you're pulling his time and attention away from the real problem.

Comment: Hm ya i suppose i never considered that, okay.

Comment: I got curious and did a little digging, and it looks like your problem might be solved by upgrading to Python 3 instead of Python 2. Without getting into the details, Python 3 has the ability to tell Windows "please just use Unicode instead of a limited system locale", whereas Python 2 is stuck with using Windows's awful, non-Unicode system locales (blech) for calling external programs. The limited nature of system locales is, I think, what's causing your problem, and upgrading to Python 3 should make it go away.

Comment: 0.o What's so... interesting about my issue? What did you google? There was nothing that i searched that could bring up any results (to improve googling skills). Anyways, i'll test it out

Comment: I work with Python, so I dug into the source code of youtube-dl. Google wouldn't have helped you with that one. :-)

Comment: nope no success, but somehow the error message leads me to believe that this is a problem with ffmpeg and not youtube-dl. Because it says   `[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\►2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4'` right? so that implies that youtube-dl passed the directory properly to ffmpeg, but that ffmpeg did something funky

Comment: Indeed. I'm not an expert in ffmpeg, so I won't be able to help you any further. But my recommendation at this point would be to use Linux, since I've been able to make it work on Linux. If you don't want to quit using Windows, look into VirtualBox and install the latest Linux Mint (I recommend the Cinnamon edition) in a virtual machine, then use that to do your downloading of music videos with funky characters. Good luck!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xr9f-hwZAtw so you could download this very video with the `youtube-dl -ci -f best -x --no-mtime --add-metadata` command?

Comment: Yes. Pasting that command into the Linux command line was successful, and ffmpeg gave me an .m4a file with apparently correct metadata (title and artist).

Comment: Then... Where's the problem? Clearly if it works on linux and not windows then this is a problem between Operating systems, right? But what part of operating systems? I thought that linux also had locales? Odd :/

Comment: As I said, it appears to be an internal ffmpeg thing and I can't help you with that. But basically, the default locale on Linux is UTF-8, which can represent all Unicode characters. Windows has been abysmally slow to transition to "Unicode everywhere", for reasons that would take WAY too much time to try to explain. They do use Unicode, but too many areas of Windows still use the abomination known as "Windows codepages" (blech) instead of true Unicode. Short (REALLY short) version: if something Unicode-related works on Linux but not on Windows, it's never surprising to me.

Comment: Anyway, this discussion is becoming WAY too long and I should get back to work. If you want to learn more about the difference between Windows and Linux in this area, I suggest Googling "unicode windows vs linux" (without quotes) as a good starting point to learn more. Good luck with your problem, and have a nice day. Or evening, or whatever it is in your time zone right now. :-)